# Post JsonObject use Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using HttpPost to post data to a backend server, and it work well with this code below :

```
     public void postData() {

        String url = Configs.URL_OWS;
        String odmName = Configs.ODM;
        String keymd5 = getKeyMD5();

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("model", model);
        jsonObject.put("imei", imei1);
        jsonObject.put("imei2", imei2);
        jsonObject.put("build", buildVersion);

        if (CommonUtils.isNetworkConnected(mContext)) {
            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

            HttpParams myParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(myParams, Configs.TIME_OUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(myParams, Configs.TIME_OUT);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(myParams);

            try {
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                httppost.addHeader("Authorization", odmName + ":" + keymd5);
                // httppost.addHeader("POST", "/api/ows HTTP/1.1");

                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
                se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                        "application/json"));

                httppost.setEntity(se);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(result);
                String status = jsonResponse.optString("status");

                if (status.equals(Configs.RESPONSE_OK)) { // response 200, send successfull
                    Log.i(Configs.APP_NAME + " " + TAG, "Send data successful");

                } else {
                    Log.i(Configs.APP_NAME + " " + TAG, "Send data failed:");
                }
            } catch (final ClientProtocolException e) {
                Log.i(Configs.APP_NAME + " " + TAG, "ClientProtocolException " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                Log.i(Configs.APP_NAME + " " + TAG, "IOException " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(Configs.APP_NAME + " " + TAG, "Network not connected ");
        }
    }
```

I switched to use Volley instead HttpPost but server always return error , the code for Volley method :

```
    public void postDataByVolley() {

        String url = Configs.URL_OWS;
        String odmName = Configs.ODM;
        final String keymd5 = getKeyMD5();

        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("model", model);
        params.put("imei", imei1);
        params.put("imei2", imei2);
        params.put("build", buildVersion);


        if (CommonUtils.isNetworkConnected(mContext)) {


            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                    Request.Method.POST,
                    url,
                    new JSONObject(params),

                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            Log.i(Configs.APP_NAME + " " + TAG, "Success ");
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.i(Configs.APP_NAME + " " + TAG, "Error: " + error.toString());

                        }
                    }) {

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
                    headers.put("Content-type", "application/json");
                    headers.put("Authorization", odmName + ":" + keymd5);
                    return headers;
                }
            };


            jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(Configs.TIME_OUT, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        }
    }
```

I can not find where I was wrong with the code for Volley method. Is there any problem in my Volley method?

Comment: Post your error log If any.

Comment: @I_Droid : Log : BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400

Comment: 400 means bad request. Check that you properly requested with headers and parameters

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say why you are facing an error .please check that url and parameters are sent correctly .once you get the error then paste error log here 
Check the following link to understand it better

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: Server response : BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 .

Comment: Just remove content type json from your header here and check if it works .400 usually means server API is not getting what exactly it expects